# Add QML(QQuickView) to existing UI

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qquickview

Currently, I am developing a Qt class that needs to be integrated in a C++ Visual Studio project.

> Qt project - Qt Widgets Application. Build on Qt Creator 3.2.1
>   (opensource), based on Qt 5.3.2.  Using Visual Studio 2013
>   Professional, the Qt Addin installed.

I tried the solutions from all over the Internet or from other Stack posts but without success. I don't see my post as a duplicate since the other posts didn't solve my problem.

I was able to run the QML from code, but it launches on a different window. In the first picture the QML window (Qt canvas) is shown over my program UI.

[image: QML on a separate window]

I need to integrate the QML into my program UI. I can use a `QGraphicsView` if it helps.

[image: ProgramUi]

Simple QML example. `canvas.qml`

```
import QtQuick 2.0
Rectangle {
    id: rectangle
    color: "red"
    width: 600
    height: 600 
}
```

Comment: How are you loading that QML file? Are you using QQuickWidget?

Comment: Yes. I am using QQuickWidget.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at a part of MVC implementation in my project. Here is a class to visualize a QML code in Qt5.6. Hope it helps.

```
QmlViewBase::QmlViewBase( QWindow* parent, const std::string& qmlFilePath)
{
    this->m_pEngine = QQmlEnginePtr( new QQmlEngine() );
    this->m_pView = QQuickViewPtr ( new QQuickView( this->m_pEngine.get(), parent ));
    this->m_pView->setResizeMode( QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView );
    this->m_pView->setSource( QUrl( qmlFilePath.c_str() ));
    this->m_pView->setVisible( false );
    this->m_pView->setMinimumSize(QSize(640, 480));
}

QmlViewBase::~QmlViewBase()
{
    try {
        this->m_pView.reset();
    }catch(...) {

    }
}

void QmlViewBase::show()
{
    this->m_pView->show();
}

void QmlViewBase::hide()
{
    this->m_pView->hide();
}

bool QmlViewBase::isVisible()
{
    return this->m_pView->isVisible();
}

bool QmlViewBase::close()
{
    return this->m_pView->close();
}

QObject * const QmlViewBase::getSlotsSignalsObject() const
{
    return reinterpret_cast<QObject* const >( this->m_pView->rootObject() );
}
```

To manage controllers I have Gui director class with the following implementation :

```
#ifndef de91_a97_4a2d_b906_01070cbfdd47
#define de91_a97_4a2d_b906_01070cbfdd47

#include "gui_director.h"
#include "utility/event_handler/event_handler.h"
#include "utility/exceptions.h"
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/weak_ptr.hpp>
#include <map>
#include <QApplication>

template<typename ControllerId>
class GuiDirectorImpl : public GuiDirector<ControllerId>,
                        public EventHandler<
                              Event<ModelToUIParameters, ServerToClientEventType> >
{
public:
   typedef boost::shared_ptr<GuiDirectorImpl<ControllerId> > pointer;
   typedef boost::weak_ptr<GuiDirectorImpl<ControllerId> > weak_pointer;

public:
   virtual ~GuiDirectorImpl()
   {
   }
   ;
   GuiDirectorImpl(QApplication *app)
   {
      m_app = app;
      m_currentActiveController.reset();
   }

   virtual void addController(ControllerId controllerId,
                              Controller::pointer controller)
   {
      if (isControllerExist( controllerId )) {
         BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION( argument_error()
                                << error_description( "controller with such id already added" ) );
      }

      m_idToController[controllerId] = controller;
   }

   virtual void setActive(ControllerId controllerId)
   {
      if (!isControllerExist( controllerId )) {
         BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION( argument_error()
                                << error_description( "controller with such id doesn't exeist" ) );
      }

      Controller::pointer oldController = m_currentActiveController;

      m_currentActiveController = m_idToController[controllerId];
      if(NULL != oldController)
      {
          oldController->prepareViewToHide();
      }
      m_currentActiveController->prepareViewToShow();

      m_currentActiveController->startShowView();

      if (NULL != oldController) {
         oldController->stopShowView();
      }
   }

   virtual void handleEvent(Event<ModelToUIParameters, ServerToClientEventType>::pointer event_)
   {
      if (NULL == m_currentActiveController) {
         BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION( error()
                                << error_description( "no active controller, cant handle event" ) );
      }

      m_currentActiveController->handleEvent( event_ );
   }

   virtual void quit()
   {
      m_app->quit();
   }

private:
   bool isControllerExist(ControllerId controllerId)
   {
      typename std::map<ControllerId, Controller::pointer>::const_iterator iter = m_idToController.find( controllerId );

      if (m_idToController.end() == iter) {
         return false;
      }

      return true;
   }

private:
   QApplication *m_app;
   Controller::pointer m_currentActiveController;
   typename std::map<ControllerId, Controller::pointer> m_idToController;
};

#endif /* de91_a97_4a2d_b906_01070cbfdd47 */
```

Comment: I like your approach, I think what Qt calls "MVC" is more a MVC framework for controls, rather than a general framework for building large applications. How do you handle switching between views?

Comment: Well, I have so-called GUI director class. I'll put it to my answer.